# "Thread 1 signal SIGABRT" when trying to code a Table View

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

My viewcontroller.Swift is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.devoncarlson.sinceextentionsharingefaults")

        sharedDefaults?.setObject("Hi I'm a Widget", forKey: "stringKey")

        sharedDefaults?.synchronize()


    }

    var eventInArray = ["Drinking"]


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return eventInArray.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
        UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
        indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = eventInArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell 
    }

    //        cell.textLabel.text = eventInArray[indexPath.row]


     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

What is causing this? It began after linking my table view to my code. Please explain your answer as if to a five year old, I'm very new to programming.

Comment: hi, welcome to SO - the code looks ok and works fine when put in a new sample project. The bug must be because you have something setup wrong in your xib

Comment: @Daij-Djan Yes. The problem is, he doesn't set the Cell-identifier in the storyboard.

Comment: so you think! it is a good guess but lets see what the OP says

Answer (score 0):

When you right-click or cmd-click and drag to the little view-controller icon, make it connected to both of the options that it gives you, I believe you have to connect to the view controller and to the delegate.  Sorry, not at my mac at the moment or I'd be more specific, but I'm pretty sure your connection to the tableview is what is doing it.

Comment: what? :) I don't get it -- he connected the datasource. the delegate is optional

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on these lines:

```
let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
        indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

As you see, you set the cellIdentifier to "Cell". Now in your UITableViewcontroller you also need to set the identifier. To do that, just click on the cell at your UITableViewController in the Storyboard and set the cell identifier:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you and found the fix, make sure the name is the same as in the identifier. Also make sure is the same name you have in App Delegate. If you followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5yd9KKwloU&feature=youtu.be) try changing the name of the Cell to MyCell.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in these code lines:

```
let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
        indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

You must make `as!` not `as`
And make your TableViewCell have an Identifier: For Example, the Identifier is ExampleIdentifier, then you put ExampleIdentifier on these two places in the .swift file of the cell[image]You must name the file ExampleIdentifier too!
Then, if you go on Menu.storyboard, and click on the cell, make, this cell has the same Identifier (here ExampleIdentifier), so the cell is linked with her file [image]Then, the cell has an identifier, so type this code

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
        indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

in

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
        indexPath) as! ExampleIdentifier
```

I hope I could help you